# Issue with tableLayoutPanel and datatable-bound CheckBoxes?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I have a `Windows Form` that displays a list of `checkboxes` within a `tableLayoutPanel`.

The checkboxes are being displayed, but the spacing between them is very odd. `tableLayoutPanelMsgs.ColumnCount` is set to 1.

This is my code:

```
DataTable messagesTable = ds.Tables[0];

foreach (DataRow row in messagesTable.Rows)
{
    CheckBox ck = new CheckBox();
    ck.Text = row[1].ToString();
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ck);
}
```

This is how the checkboxes look in the Windows Form. Notice the spacing between each Checkbox.
[image]

How can I fix this? Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `RowStyle`.

*See the attached screenshot to set the `Properties`*:

[image]

There must be at least one row, and you need to set it's style. The rest of the rows will be added automatically with default style as `AutoSize`.

Answer (score 0):

Call [SetRow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.setrow(v=vs.110).aspx) for each checkbox added to place it in a separate row inside `tableLayoutPanel1`:

```
DataTable messagesTable = ds.Tables[0];
int I = 0;

tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = messagesTable.Rows.Count;

foreach (DataRow row in messagesTable.Rows)
{
    CheckBox ck = new CheckBox();
    ck.Text = row[1].ToString();
    tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(ck);
    tableLayoutPanel1.SetRow(ck, i++);
}
```